# Order with group rows together

Tags: mysql

Having problem with complex order.

Here is structure and data:

```
CREATE TABLE `mail_test` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `account_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `score` float UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `from` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


INSERT INTO `mail_test` (`id`, `account_id`, `score`, `from`) VALUES
(1, 1, 0, 'a@a.com'),
(2, 2, 0, 'b@b.com'),
(3, 3, 3, 'c@c.com'),
(4, 5, 4, 'm@m.com'),
(5, 3, 1, 'c@c.com'),
(6, 9, 0.5, 'z@z.com'),
(7, 9, 3, 'z@p.com'),
(8, 8, 2, 'z@p.com');
```

Desired output:

```
(4, 5, 4, 'm@m.com'),
(7, 9, 3, 'z@p.com'),
(3, 3, 3, 'c@c.com'),
(5, 3, 1, 'c@c.com'),
(8, 8, 2, 'z@p.com');
(6, 9, 0.5, 'z@z.com'),
(1, 1, 0, 'a@a.com'),
(2, 2, 0, 'b@b.com'),
```

The order logic: first is row with greatest score (parent row), then rows (child rows) with same `account_id` and `from` with parent row. If no child rows - again next row with great score. So order by score DESC. But rows grouped by same `account_id` and `from`.

mysql version 5.7

Comment: Please add your desired outcome.

Comment: What is **complex** about sorting order? What did you try (to write yourself) to get your desired output ?

Comment: @Mikael I have added the query in the answer. Try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM mail_test
ORDER BY MAX(score) OVER (PARTITION BY account_id, `from`) DESC,
         account_id, `from`,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY account_id, `from` ORDER BY score DESC)
```

| id | account_id | score | from |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 5 | 4 | m@m.com |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | c@c.com |
| 5 | 3 | 1 | c@c.com |
| 7 | 9 | 3 | z@p.com |
| 8 | 8 | 2 | z@p.com |
| 6 | 9 | 0.5 | z@z.com |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | a@a.com |
| 2 | 2 | 0 | b@b.com |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wcj5ZVaa)

Comment: @Mikael Correct - the groups may have equal maximal score. Fixed. The groups (3,5) and (7) in my output does not match the ordering in your desired output - but you have not provided needed criteria for such groups sorting. For example, this can be fixed by `.. ORDER BY .. account_id DESC, ..`.

Comment: is it possible on mysql 5.7 ? sorry, I have updated post, mysql version is 5.7

Comment: Emulate window functions with according JOIN + GROUP BY, or use user-defined variables.. but I recommend you to upgrade your MySQL version.

Comment: And how do you think, if I upgrade from 5.7 to 8 - there high chances to get something broken ?

Comment: @Mikael 50/50 - either success or not. Backup (checked for its restorability) will help.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using `row_number()` and `max()` :

```
with cte as (
  select *,
           max(score) over (partition by account_id, `from`) as max_score,
           row_number() over (partition by account_id, `from` order by score, id) as rn
  from mail_test
)
select id, account_id, score, `from`
from cte
order by max_score desc, rn desc
```

This is a working solution on mysql 5.7 :

```
select mt.*
from `mail_test` mt
inner join (
  select account_id, `from`, max(score) as max_score
  from `mail_test`
  group by account_id, `from`
) as s on s.account_id = mt.account_id and s.`from` = mt.`from`
order by max_score desc, id
```

Result :

```
id  account_id  score   from
4   5           4       m@m.com
3   3           3       c@c.com
5   3           1       c@c.com
7   9           3       z@p.com
8   8           2       z@p.com
6   9           0.5     z@z.com
1   1           0       a@a.com
2   2           0       b@b.com
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/1bDwJCqJ)

Answer (score 0):

This version works without partitions:

```
SELECT m.`id`, m.`account_id`, m.`score`, m.`from`
FROM mail_test m
LEFT JOIN mail_test parent_m
  ON m.account_id = parent_m.account_id
  AND m.from = parent_m.from
  AND m.score < parent_m.score
GROUP BY m.id, m.account_id, m.score, m.from
ORDER BY IFNULL(MAX(parent_m.score), m.`score`) DESC
```

Comment: Almost perfect ! But c@c.com with score 3 must be above c@c.com with score 1

Comment: I tweaked a little, should show the correct order now (although with ambiguity over the relative ordering of id 3 and id 7)